# Opencv c++ resize function: new Width should be multiplied by 3

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, resize

I am programming in Qt environment and I have a Mat image with size 2592x2048 and I want to resize it to the size of a "label" that I have. But when I want to show the image, I have to multiply the width by 3, so the image is shown in its correct size. Is there any explanation for that?

This is my code:

```
//Here I get image from the a buffer and save it into a Mat image.
//img_width is 2592 and img_height is 2048
Mat image = Mat(cv::Size(img_width, img_height), CV_8UC3, (uchar*)img, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
Mat cimg;
double r; int n_width, n_height;
//Get the width of label (lbl) into which I want to show the image
n_width = ui->lbl->width();
r = (double)(n_width)/img_width;
n_height = r*(img_height);
cv::resize(image, cimg, Size(n_width*3, n_height), INTER_AREA);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Explain what exactly means: *so the image is shown in its correct size*, you could show an image of what you get.

Comment: @Soroor: Don't have OpenCV to try, but my guess is that you need to pass the number of bytes per line, which means the number of pixels per line (width) and multiply by bytes per pixel, and finally to obtain the size of your uncompressed image, multiply by the height! So my guess is that you need to pass the number of bytes of the image which may be or not equal to number of pixels!

Comment: 3*width is the stride, that's why you need it. It's the number of bytes per line, and assuming you have 3 channels, here is what the 3 comes from

Comment: @eyllanesc yes exactly, with 3 I get what I want. Sorry for my vague description.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Antonion Dias 
So my question is if I need to pass the number of bytes per line, why only to the width? and not to the height? I had also the same guess and changed the image type to 8UC1 but again the problem existed...

Answer (score 1):

The resize function works well, because if you save the resized image as a file is displayed correctly. Since you want to display it on QLabel, I assume you have to transform your image to QImage first and then to QPixmap. I believe the problem lies either in the step or the image format.

If we ensure the image data passed in

```
Mat image = Mat(cv::Size(img_width, img_height), CV_8UC3, (uchar*)img, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
```

are indeed an RGB image, then below code  should work:

```
ui->lbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(cimg.data, cimg.cols, cimg.rows, *cimg.step.p, QImage::Format_RGB888 )));
```

Finally, instead of using OpenCV, you could construct a QImage object using the constructor

```
QImage((uchar*)img, img_width, img_height, QImage::Format_RGB888)
```

and then use the [scaledToWidth](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scaledToWidth) method to do the resize. (beware thought that this method **returns** the scaled image, and does not performs the resize operation to the image per se)